# C: Evaluating Expression in a queue not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a queue using linked list that takes a string in the format `1 + 3 + 5 =`or `1-3+2-4 =` but the following code which is supposed to do the calculation given the sign and produce the answer is not working right for example if I passed a string like `66 - 31 - 21 + 43 =` is passed the answer turns out to be `-47` instead of `57`. Can someone help me solve it or point to what I'm doing wrong.

```
void printQueue(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* temp;
    char *token, *del=" ";
    int total = 0;

    while (head != NULL)
    {

        token = strtok(head->data, del);
        while (token != NULL) {
            int a = strcmp(token, "+");
            int b = strcmp(token, "-");
            if (a == 0)
            {
                printf("+");
                total = total + *token;
            }
            else if (b == 0) {
                printf("+");
                total = total - *token;
            }

            printf("%s ", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
        }

        printf(" %d\n",subtraction);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, such problems are then very easy to solve.

Comment: `total = total + *token;` is `total = total + '+';`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is ignoring the numbers, adding up character codes of `'+'` and `'-'` characters instead. The number `-47` is the result of computing -45-45+43: 45 is the character code for the dash; 43 is the character code for the plus.

In order to work properly, make these changes to your code:

- Add a `sign` variable of `int` type, with the initial value of `1`
- When you see a plus sign, set the `sign` to `1`
- When you see a minus sign, set the `sign` to `-1`
- When you see a token that is neither a plus nor minus, convert it to an `int val` (e.g. by calling `atoi`), and add `val * sign` to the running total.

This change will make your code work for valid expressions, but it would not fail for some invalid ones. For example, it would take "expressions" such as `1 2 3` as if it were `1+2+3`, and so on.

Comment: your solution and thinking really got me close to getting done but when given a list of strings the code will output the right answers for the first two strings then on the third string it will change signs and give the wrong answer then give the right answer for the fourth and wrong answer for the last one.

Comment: @GeekyCoder My guess is that your code is either (1) not re-assigning `sign` when it sees a `'+'` or `'-'` character, or (2) re-assigns `sign` before or after each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes you were right I don't why I couldn't see that after reassigning sign = 1 after every loop this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few oddities in your code, here's a few:

1. Your inner loop that checks if token != NULL always has 1 iteration, it probably should be an if statement
2. You are searching only for the tokens '+' and '-' and adding their character value to your total, rather than the next number, you are ignoring the tokens that hold numbers
3. When subtracting you are still printing '+' to the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value; 
    struct node *next; 
} Node;

typedef struct queque {
    Node *top;
    Node *tail;
} Queque;

Queque *Q_new(void){
    return calloc(1, sizeof(Queque));
}

void Q_enq(Queque *q, int value){
    Node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));

    if(!node) exit((printf("failed Securing memory\n"),1));
    node->value = value;

    q->tail = q->top ? (q->tail->next = node) : (q->top = node);
}

Node *Q_deq(Queque *q){
    if(q->top){
        Node *node = q->top;
        q->top = q->top->next;
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Q_drop(Queque *q){
    Node *node;
    while(node = Q_deq(q))
        free(node);
    free(q);
}

void strToQ(const char *str, Queque *q){
    char *p = (char*)str;
    int num;

    while(*p){
        if(isspace(*p)){
            ++p;
            continue;
        } else if(*p == '+' || *p == '-' || *p == '='){//not used to a number sign
            Q_enq(q, *p++);
            continue;
        }
        num = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        Q_enq(q, num);
    }
}

int Q_calc(Queque *q){
    int total = 0;
    Node *node = Q_deq(q);
    if(!node)
        return 0;

    total = node->value;
    free(node);
    while(node = Q_deq(q)){
        if(node->value == '='){
            free(node);
            break;
        } else {
            int op = node->value;
            free(node);
            node = Q_deq(q);//NOT NULL(if NULL then invalid syntax)
            if(op == '+')
                total += node->value;
            else if(op == '-')
                total -= node->value;
            free(node);
        }
    }
    return total;
}

int main(){
    Queque *q = Q_new();
    strToQ("1 + 3 + 5 =", q);
    printf("%d\n", Q_calc(q));//9, q to be empty
    strToQ("1-3+2-4 =", q);
    printf("%d\n", Q_calc(q));//-4
    strToQ("66 - 31 - 21 + 43 =", q);
    printf("%d\n", Q_calc(q));//57
    Q_drop(q);
}
```