# How do I insert data from a file into the nodes of a queue?

Tags: c, file, data-structures, insert, queue

I'm trying to insert data from a file ("input.txt") into a queue and I'm having trouble.

input.txt is as follows:

```
2   18.487.548-k    Juan    Rodriguez   35  m
122 19.658.568-0    Chewbacca   Solo    900 m
5   16.658.487-6    John    Travolta    45  m
23  10.658.479-5    Perl    Diamond 18  f
```

note: the "space" between the data is a tab ("\t") and not a space.

This are my data structures:

```
/* Person */
typedef struct person {
  int attentionNumber;
  char id [30];
  char firstName [40];
  char lastName [40];
  int age;
  char sex[20];
}Person;

/* Node */
typedef struct node {
  Person *person;
  struct node *next;
}Node;

/* Queue*/
typedef struct queue {
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int size;
}Queue;
```

Functions I'm using:

```
Queue *createQueue();
Node *createNode(Person *aPerson, Node *ptro);
void insert(Person *aPerson, int attentionNumber, char id [30], char firstName [40], char lastName [40], int age, char sex [20]);
void read();
Node *headNode(Queue *c);
Node *tailNode(Queue *c);
bool emptyQueue(Queue *c);
```

Program:

```
Queue *createQueue()
{
    Queue *aQueue;

    /* memory for the Queue */
    if((aQueue = (Queue *) malloc(sizeof(Queue))))
    {
        /* Queue initialize empty */
        aQueue->size = 0;
        /* head and tail pointer -> Null */
        aQueue->head = aQueue->tail = NULL;
    }
    return aQueue;
}

Node *createNode(Person *aPerson, Node *pointer)
{
    Node *aNode;

    /* memory for the Node */
    if((aNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node))))
    {
        /* values of Node */
        aNode->person = aPerson;
        aNode->next = pointer;
    }
    return aNode;
}

void insert(Person *aPerson, int attentionNumber, char id [30], char firstName [40], char lastName[40], int age, char sex[20])
{
    if(aPerson = (Person *) malloc(sizeof(Person)))
    {
        aPerson->attentionNumber = attentionNumber;
        strcpy(aPerson->id, id);
        strcpy(aPerson->firstName, firstName);
        strcpy(aPerson->lastName, lastName);
        aPerson->age = age;
        strcpy(aPerson->sex, sex);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't insert data\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}    

/* first node of Queue */
Node *headNode(Queue *c)
{
    return c->head;
}

/* last node of Queue */
Node *tailNode(Queue *c)
{
    return c->tail;
}

/* returns true if Queue is empty, false otherwise */
bool emptyQueue(Queue *c)
{
    return (c->head == NULL) ? true : false;
}

void read()
{

    Queue * C;
    C = createQueue();

    /* Files to read and write, respectively */
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;

    /* String to be read */
    char data[201];

    /* Temp auxiliar Person */
    Person tempPerson;

    /* Tokenize */
    char * token;

    /* Open input file */
    input = fopen("input.txt" , "r");

    /* not sure abour this */
    if(input == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Open output file for test */
    output = fopen("output.txt" , "w");

    /* Read string */
    while(fgets(data, 201, input) != NULL)
    {

        /* Tokenize by "\t" (tab) */
        token = strtok(data,"\t");

        /* Count */ 
        int count = 0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                tempPerson.attentionNumber = atoi(token);
            }

            if(count == 1)
            {
                strcpy(tempPerson.id, token);
            }

            if(count == 2)
            {
                strcpy(tempPerson.firstName, token);
            }
            if(count == 3)
            {
                strcpy(tempPerson.lastName, token);
            }
            if(count == 4)
            {
                tempPerson.age = atoi(token);
            }
            if(count == 5)
            {
                strcpy(tempPerson.sex, token);
            }
            count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
        }

        /* Call insert function */
        insert(tempPerson, tempPerson.attentionNumber, tempPerson.id, tempPerson.firstName, tempPerson.lastName, tempPerson.age, tempPerson.sex);

        /* Write output file for test */
        fprintf(output, " %i ", tempPerson.attentionNumber);
        fprintf(output, "%s ", tempPerson.id);
        fprintf(output, "%s ", tempPerson.firstName);
        fprintf(output, "%s ", tempPerson.lastName);
        fprintf(output, "%i ", tempPerson.age);
        fprintf(output, "%s", tempPerson.sex);

    }

    /* Close files */       
    fclose(input);      
    fclose(output);
}

int main (int argc , char ** argv)
{
    /* Call read function */
    read();

    return 0;

}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
In function ‘read’:
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘insert’
   insert(tempPerson, tempPerson.attentionNumber, tempPerson.id, tempPerson.firstName, tempPerson.lastName, tempPerson.age, tempPerson.sex);
   ^
note: expected ‘struct Person *’ but argument is of type ‘Person’
 void insert(Person *aPerson, int attentionNumber, char id [30], char firstName [40], char lastName[40], int age, char sex[20])
```

What am I doing wrong/not doing?

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` to/from pointers (like the result of `malloc()` & friends). Use `strcpy` without catuion, it will exhibit _undefined behaviour_ if the source does not fit into destination - account for the extra terminator.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, nor "write my code". There are thousands of implementations for lists around. Even on SO.

Comment: Why are you compiling without compiler warnings? I'm pretty sure your compiler would *love*  to tell you what it thinks of `new_person.sex = token);` , which, mismatched bracket aside, is attempting to assign a `char *` to a `char`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just didn't find any, I am actually asking for help, not asking for you to "write my code"...

So maybe I guess I am searching wrong, could you show me the thousands of implementations for lists there are on SO so I can apply a solution to my question?

Comment: Then your question is badly worded. For the examples, just look around. Also do as @EOF proposed. Make that an MCVE and ask properly.

Comment: what is an MCVE?

How do you recommend I edit my question so it's not badly worded? English is not my native language so I always struggle with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (English is also not my native language, but this is an english-speaking forum, so we need some common denominator. However, I do not criticise your language.) Instead of complaining, you could already have compiled with warnings enabled, corrected the problems and searched a bit. If you do not like google, try [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30852441/971127

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25006135/971127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so instead of:

```
insert(tempPerson, tempPerson.attentionNumber, tempPerson.id, tempPerson.firstName, tempPerson.lastName, tempPerson.age, tempPerson.sex);
```

It should be:

```
insert(&tempPerson, tempPerson.attentionNumber, tempPerson.id, tempPerson.firstName, tempPerson.lastName, tempPerson.age, tempPerson.sex);
```